# Google recaptcha in form, email won't send

Tags: php, recaptcha

I worked Google's Captcha into my html form and into the php handler. When I fill in the form (and do correctly), I get the message MAIL SEND but I think the php is not sending an email. I'm not receiving any mails... This form and php worked without recaptcha but now I think there's a mistake in my code. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

// grab recaptcha library
require_once "recaptchalib.php";

// your secret key
$secret = "---";

// empty response
$response = null;

// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

// if submitted check response
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
$response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
    $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "---@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Contact ---.synology.me";
$name_field = $_POST['username'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$password1 = $_POST['pwd1'];
$password2 = $_POST['pwd2'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$body = " NL\n Afzender: $name_field\n Geslacht: $sex\n Emailadres: 
$email_field\n Wachtwoord 1: $password1\n Wachtwoord 2: $password2\n 
Suggestie: $comment\n";

echo "<script>
if(confirm('MAIL SEND!')){
    window.location.href = 'https://---.synology.me/account-aanvragen.html';
}else{
    window.location.href = 'https://---.synology.me/account-aanvragen.html';
}
</script>";

$headers = "From: ---@hotmail.com" . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
} else {
echo "Er ging iets mis, probeer opnieuw of contacteer de administrator op ---@hotmail.com!";
}


} else {
echo "<script>
if(confirm('Bevestig dat je geen robot bent!')){
    window.location.href = 'https://---.synology.me/account-aanvragen.html';
}else{
    window.location.href = 'https://---.synology.me/account-aanvragen.html';
}
</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm betting your code is fine - it's the `mail` function that relies on your server or DNS configuration. I typically delegate email to a 3rd party API like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) or [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Comment: Wild guess, maybe wrong: your mail() function is after the js location.href . Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send email from ...@hotmail.com without SMTP protocol.Your emails probably sended but hotmail is probably rejected your email thinking it's spam.So you should use smtp and log in with your password and email.

You can use [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send email.

Answer (score 1):

I always use a library or framework method to send emails. There are many and distinct problems that you find in this process, from server configuration, escape of content mail, headers and more.
I recommend that use [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for example. With this library you will be trace the process and detect your problem.